Wix Form not saving dynamic information
I have a WIX form in which I want to send the referral information to a CRM.  It is not even saving the information in it's own inbox.  The code I am using is as follows.  This is all javascript.
import wixWindowFrontend from 'wix-window-frontend';
let referrer = wixWindowFrontend.referrer;
    
$w.onReady(function () {        
    $w('#input7').value = referrer.toString();
    $w('#input7').valid = true;
    console.log(referrer.toString());// Write your JavaScript here
});

The console write is correct, but I do not get the information to the inbox for the form and as such is not going to the CRM.
if I hard code the referrer it is stored and saved.  I do not know what I have missed or done wrong.
I am expecting the hidden field to retain the information sent by javascript.
